# Javascript- Make JSON sort function extensible for Date object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, date

While this function works fine for strings and numbers, because I am using the `===` comparison operator for Date objects it doesn't extend.

```
function getDataCounted(objects, key) {
let ret = [];
let groups = objects
    .reduce((accumulator, element, index, array) => {
        if (accumulator.indexOf(element[key]) < 0 &&
            array.findIndex(elm => elm[key].getTime() === array[key].getTime()) < index)
            accumulator.push(element[key]);
        return accumulator;
    }, [])
    .forEach(group => {
        let count = 0;
        objects.forEach(object => {
            if (object[key] === group) {
                count++;
            }
        });
        ret.push([
            group,
            count
        ])
    });
ret.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);
return ret;
}
```

I tried:

```
    let groups = objects
    .reduce((accumulator, element, index, array) => {
        if (element instanceof Date) {
            if (accumulator.indexOf(element[key]) < 0 //
                &&
                array.findIndex(elm => elm[key].getTime() === array[key].getTime()) < index)
                accumulator.push(element[key]);
            return accumulator;
        }
        if (accumulator.indexOf(element[key]) < 0 &&
            array.findIndex(elm => elm[key] === array[key]) < index)
            accumulator.push(element[key]);
        return accumulator;
    }, [])
```

but no.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bulldoglowell/andqu5jb/22/)

Comment: Can you please add an example of your function being used?

Comment: @pwilcox, I added a fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Replace `ret.sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]);`

With:

```
  ret.sort((a, b) => {
    if (a[0] instanceof Date) {
      return a[0].getTime() - b[0].getTime();
    }
    else {
      return a[0] - b[0];
    }
  });
```

[Updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hynkg6b3/)

Comment: Thanks but the sort isn't the issue.  The problem is how to handle the equality operator in the accumulator.

Comment: What is the problem then? What are you trying to achieve and why?

Comment: I am trying to make the function extensible for keys which hold date values.  I am filtering the array of objects by key.  The key values could be numeric, strings or dates.

Comment: How about converting the Dates to string with iso format (YYYY-mm-dd) so you can use lexicographic order ?